# How does on marshal class parameters to COM methods?

Tags: c#, vbscript, com, pinvoke

I have a class defined in VBSript:

```
Class Foo
  Public i
End Class
```

of which I want to pass an instance to a COM object written in C#:

```
Dim oCOMTEST : Set oCOMTEST = CreateObject("COMTests.Class1")

Dim oFoo : Set oFoo = new Foo
oFoo.i = 42
Call oCOMTEST.M(oFoo)
```

The method `M` is defined as:

```
public void M(ref object foo)
```

Currently the method expects an `object` but I would rather have the method
take a C#-equivalent type of `Foo`. Among others I have tried changing `object`
to `Foo`, with

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Foo
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
  public int i;
}
```

but without success. Therefore my question is:

*How does the marshaled C# version of the VBScript type `Foo` look like?*

--

This is my minimal test case.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace COMTests
{
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("4624071F-2D98-4ECC-8898-558F4D24EEC9")]
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
  public interface IClass1
  {
    void M(ref object foo);
  }

  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("9F2B6958-742F-4E5D-A5F3-D6BDC6C841DB")]
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  [ProgId("COMTests.Class1")]
  public class Class1 : IClass1
  {
    public void M(ref object foo)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    }
  }
}
```

And the following VBScript:

```
Dim oCOMTEST : Set oCOMTEST = CreateObject("COMTests.Class1")

Dim oFoo : Set oFoo = new Foo
oFoo.i = 42
Call oCOMTEST.M(oFoo)

Class Foo
  Public i
End Class
```

Comment: Good question. In VB6, in addition to creating a CLSID for you behind the scenes, VB automatically creates an interface for every class you create. Your `Foo` class would get an automatic `_Foo` interface and an associated `IID__Foo` identifier (note the two underscores). I would assume VBScript does something similar.

Comment: You can't, the scripting engine only supports late-binding.  Using the *dynamic* keyword is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VBScript class is not a full COM object because it has no IID (interface ID) associated with it. So, I may be wrong, but I don't think you can have it match a .NET class or interface (many attributes such as `ComImport` expect an associated Guid attribute). It could work if Foo was created from a "real" COM object. In the background, I believe the VBScript's Foo object implements `IDispatch` only, so it's by nature very dynamic.

However, you can still use its properties and metods quite easily with the c# `dynamic` pseudo-type keyword, for example, the following code should work fine:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("9F2B6958-742F-4E5D-A5F3-D6BDC6C841DB")]
[ProgId("COMTests.Class1")]
public class Class1
{
    public void M(dynamic foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo:" + foo.i);
    }
}
```

PS: You do not need the interface or the ref attribute in this context. With my code above, this is what will get created automatically by .NET (in IDL terms, a bit simplified for readability):

```
[
  uuid(E66DC08B-A63A-41A8-B63D-15ED6F4569AB),
  version(1.0),
]
library ClassLibrary1
{
    interface _Class1;

    [
      uuid(9F2B6958-742F-4E5D-A5F3-D6BDC6C841DB),
      version(1.0),
    ]
    coclass Class1 {
        [default] interface _Class1;
        interface _Object;
    };

    [
      odl,
      uuid(F56AF0FC-D93B-399E-8FBD-9B72CF50D7D9),
      hidden,
      dual,
      oleautomation,
    ]
    interface _Class1 : IDispatch {
    };
};
```

Comment: Are you sure about not needing `  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]`. When I open the generated `tlb` adding/removing the `ClassInterface(...)` shows different results.

Comment: Yes, it's different, but in this context, you only need what's in my code (you don't need `ClassInterfaceAttribute`, you don't need an `IClass1` class, and you don't need the argument passed as `ref`). This was just a remark, you can let the code as it was initially if you prefer it that way.

Comment: Can you please explain, why one does not need those things. I would like to understand.

Comment: Because it works fine without it as .NET automatically creates an IDispatch interface and VBScript can call IDispatch interfaces. See my update.